# According to Catholicism, is Jesus' resurrected body in a certain location now that it has ascended?

Tags: catholicism, ascension

According to Catholicism, does Jesus still have his resurrected body, and if so is it in a certain location now that it has ascended?

Answer (score 1):

He ascended **body and soul** into **heaven**.

[*Catechism of the Council of Trent*](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/trentc.htm) ([eBook](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=5864)) on [Article 6 of the Creed, "He ascended into heaven…"](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/ApostlesCreed06.shtml):

> ### First Part of this Article: "He Ascended into Heaven"
>
> With regard, then, to the exposition of this sixth Article, which has
> reference principally to this divine mystery, we shall begin with its
> first part, and point out its force and meaning.
>
> #### "Into Heaven"
>
> This, then, the faithful must believe without hesitation, that Jesus
> Christ, having fully accomplished the work of Redemption, ascended as
> man, body and soul, into heaven; for as God He never forsook heaven,
> filling as He does all places with His Divinity.
>
> #### "He Ascended"
>
> The pastor is also to teach that He ascended by His own power, not
> being taken up by the power of another, as was Elias, who was carried
> to heaven in a fiery chariot; or, as the Prophet Habacuc, or Philip,
> the deacon, who were borne through the air by the divine power, and
> traversed great distances.
>
> Neither did He ascend into heaven solely by the exercise of His
> supreme power as God, but also by virtue of the power which He
> possessed as man. Although human power alone was insufficient to
> accomplish this, yet the virtue with which the blessed soul of Christ
> was endowed was capable of moving the body as it pleased, and His
> body, now glorified, readily obeyed the behest of the soul that moved
> it. Hence, we believe that Christ ascended into heaven as God and man
> by His own power.

Comment: +1 Is Heaven a location?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg Yes, heaven is a place. See [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/81175/1787) and references therein.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus body? Earth was the same body as all of us!  From the dust of the ground was his flest taken.   Jesus as a child was like all other children.For a time.
HE CHRIST return to God!  His flesh did not!  Can you see our flesh is space?
Then we knew nothing of how massive universities, Stars and planets,
we can not see.
Christ returned to his father.  As we come from the dead!  Our body will not be made of clay.  Fr. Goad Tucson AZ